# "Ambiguous output redirect" trying to send both stdout and stderr to mailx from a command sent to at

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, io-redirection

I have a bash script called *test.sh* which, for the sake of simplicity, prints one line to *stdout* and one line to *stderr*.

**test.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "this is to stdout"
echo "this is to stderr" 1>&2
```

I want to run the script *test.sh* at 7:00 PM, but only if certain conditions are met. To this end, I have another bash script called *schedule.sh*, which checks some stuff and then submits the command to `at` to be run later.

I want the output of *test.sh* (both *stdout* and *stderr*) to be sent to me in an email. I use `mailx` to do this so I can get a nice subject name.

Furthermore, I want `at` to shut up. No output from `at` because it always sends me ugly emails (no subject line) if `at` produces any output.

**schedule.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
my_email="me@example.com" # Email is a variable
# Check some stuff, exit if certain conditions not met
echo "~/test.sh 2>&1 | mailx -s\"Cool title\" $my_email" | at 7:00 PM &> /dev/null
```

What's interesting is that when I run *schedule.sh* from `cron` (which runs the script with `sh`), it works perfectly. However, when I manually run *schedule.sh* from the terminal (NB: I'm using `tcsh`), `at` (not `mailx`) sends me an email saying

```
Ambiguous output redirect.
```

I'm not sure why the shell I run *schedule.sh* from makes a difference, when *schedule.sh* is a bash script.

Here is my thinking in looking at *schedule.sh*. Everything within the quotation marks `"~/test.sh 2>&1 | mailx -s\"Cool title\" me@email.com"` should be an argument to `at`, and `at` runs that argument as a command using `sh`. The redirection `2>&1 |` is in the style of `sh` for this reason.

When I remove `2>&1` and only pipe the *stdout* of *test.sh* to `mailx`, it does work; however, I receive 2 emails: one with *stdout* from `mailx` and another from *stderr* from `at`.

What gives? How can I make this work regardless of the shell I'm calling it from?

Thanks.

**edit:**

`uname -o` says my OS is `GNU/Linux`

Here is `uname -a` if it helps:

```
Linux [hostname censored] 2.6.9-89.ELlargesmp #1 SMP Mon Jun 22 12:46:58 EDT 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When I check the `at` contents using `at -c`, here's what I see:

```
#!/bin/sh
# atrun uid=xxxxx gid=xxxxx
# mail  username 0
# ...
SHELL=/bin/tcsh; export SHELL
# ...
${SHELL:-/bin/sh} << `(dd if=/dev/urandom count=200 bs=1 2>/dev/null|LC_ALL=C tr -d -c '[:alnum:]')`

~/test.sh 2>&1 | mailx -s"Cool title" me@example.com
```

I'm having a hard time understanding the second to last line... is this going to execute using $SHELL or `/bin/sh`?

Comment: More thoughts: the fact that `at` delivers the error message seems to indicate that it's the `echo "..."` part that is causing the failure. Any reason why? Even though `2>&1 |` is not valid redirection format in `bash` (right?), it shouldn't matter because it's just part of a string that should be piped to `at` which runs `sh`...

Comment: `2>&1 |` is perfectly valid in bash. bash is designed to be backward compatible with sh. (On some systems, `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `/bin/bash`.)

Comment: So it's `tcsh` giving the error? But it's in a `bash` script... Doesn't `#!/bin/bash` allow me to start using `bash`-fu?

Comment: If you have `schedule.sh` as a command in your crontab, then crontab uses `/bin/sh` to execute the command, but the script itself will be executed by bash because of the `#!/bin/bash`. And `at` uses `/bin/sh` to execute the commands that it reads on its standard input.

Comment: Can you put `ps -p $$; ` in your command to verify that `at` executes the command as `sh`? This is exactly the error you'd get if the command ran with tcsh.

Comment: "Ambiguous output redirect." is a csh/tcsh error message. How *exactly* are you executing `schedule.sh`? (But when I feed your script to tcsh, I get "Invalid null command.".)

Comment: @thatotherguy: No, it isn't; the `my_email=$1` line would produce a "Command not found" error.

Comment: Have you shown is the *exact* (copy-and-pasted) contents of `schedule.sh`?

Comment: @KeithThompson: apologies, I just wanted to emphasize that `my_email` is variable. I changed it to `my_email="me@domain.com"`. Other than that, and the fact that I replaced 7:00 PM with `now + 1 minutes` for debugging, the scripts are exactly that now.

Comment: @thatotherguy: I changed it to `echo "ps -p $$; ..." | at ...` but I still only see "Ambigious output redirection". I can't see the output. I can see from `at -c` that the first line of the batch file is `#!/bin/sh`

Comment: @EvanW - The first line you saw is just the initial shell that `at` uses to setup the environment. If you look closely, you'll see that it sets up SHELL with the login shell of the owner and uses it to run the code. In short, `at` uses the same shell as the owner's shell. Instead of executing a line of code passed to `at` wrap the line of code in a script or runt it in a sub-shell. It will be ugly when `at` forks its shell then forks your login shell and then finally your fork another shell.

Comment: @alvits: That is a big "OH!" Thanks for clearing that up... wonder if I can just squash SHELL with "sh"

Comment: How do you plan to squash it when your code is executed by this new `SHELL`? You could fork another shell instead and execute your code in it.

Comment: `domain.com` is a real domain name. Use `example.com` for sample e-mail addresses.

Comment: Okay, so from `tcsh`, I spawned `sh`. From `sh`, I executed `schedule.sh`; and I still get "Ambiguous output redirect."

Comment: @alvits: The `at` man page on my system says: "`at` and `batch` read commands from standard input or a specified file which are to be executed at a later time, using `/bin/sh`."

Comment: @EvanW: From `sh` try `SHELL=/bin/sh ./schedule.sh`. And check `man at` on your system; does it say it uses `/bin/sh` or `$SHELL`?

Comment: @KeithThompson - If you look at the code generated when running `at` you will see that it will set `SHELL` from the login shell of the owner or from whatever value it is currently set while creating the job. The code then uses `${SHELL} << hereDoc` and puts the code inside the hereDoc.

Comment: @EvanW - No matter what shell you use to invoke schedule.sh, when `schedule.sh` executes `at` command, the `at` command will set the `SHELL` variable to your login shell or to the current value that this variable is set to. I'd suggest setting this variable `SHELL` to `/bin/bash` or `/bin/sh` inside `schedule.sh`.

Comment: @KeithThompson - On solaris there's switches you can use to tell `at` which shell to use. In the absence of this switch, `at` uses the SHELL variable to determine which shell to use. Therefore the behavior for both Solaris and Linux are the same.

Comment: @alvits: No, on Linux (at least on Linux Mint 14), it consistently uses `/bin/sh` regardless of `$SHELL`; see my answer. Evan: Please update your question to indicate which OS you're using; it turns out that it matters.

Comment: @KeithThompson - I have to agree with you. I only checked them on Oracle Enterprise Linux (variant of RedHat) and on Solaris.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command executed via `at` is:

```
~/test.sh 2>&1 | mailx -s\"Cool title\" $my_email
```

The behavior of `at` command varies from one system to another. On Linux, the command is executed using `/bin/sh`. In fact, on my system (Linux Mint 14), it prints a warning message:

```
$ echo 'printenv > at.env' | at 19:24
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
```

On Solaris, the command is executed by the shell specified by the current value of the `$SHELL` environment variable. Using an account where my default shell is `/bin/tcsh` on Solaris 9, I get:

```
% echo 'printenv > at.env' | at 19:25
commands will be executed using /bin/tcsh
job 1397874300.a at Fri Apr 18 19:25:00 2014
% echo 'printenv > at.env' | env SHELL=/bin/sh at 19:28
commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 1397874480.a at Fri Apr 18 19:28:00 2014
```

Given that `at`'s behavior is inconsistent (and frankly confusing), I suggest having it execute just a single command, with any I/O redirection being performed inside that command. That's the best way to ensure that the command will be executed correctly regardless of which shell is used to execute it.

For example (untested code follows):

```
echo '#!/bin/bash' > tmp.bash
echo "~/test.sh 2>&1 | mailx -s\"Cool title\" $my_email" >> tmp.bash
chmod +x tmp.bash
echo "./tmp.bash" | at 7:00 PM
```

Comment: +1; `at` on OSX (and thus, I assume, on all BSD-derived systems) also always uses `sh`.

Comment: In the end I opted for putting the command in a separate bash script and making `at` execute that script... although I feel like this should've been easier... thanks for your help!